# Uppercase return for total

Tags: linux, shell, awk

The following command prints a modified output of `wc -l`:

```
$ wc -l *.c *.h | awk '{print $2":"$1}'
file1.c:1000
file2.c:0
file3.h:5
total:1005
```

The last line has the word `total` which represents the total number of lines of the output. Anyone know how I can change that line so that it is capitalized?

```
file1.c:1000
file2.c:0
file3.h:5
TOTAL:1005
```

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add 3 simple things in your post. 1- samples of input, 2- samples of output and 3rd- most importantly add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: You have to be more specific on the problem you are facing.

Comment: Im sorry about my unclear question but this was my first post here.And thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
$ wc -l *.c *.h | awk '(NR>1){print t}{t=$2":"$1}END{print "TOTAL:"$1}'
```

As indicated in the [comment of Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179884/uppercase-return-for-total/55180228?noredirect=1#comment97106815_55180228), this method is not as robust as it seems. A more robust system can be found in the [answer of stack0114106](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181604/8344060) or alternatively

```
$ wc -l *.c *.h | awk '(NR>1){print t1":"t2}{t1=$2;t2=$1}END{print "TOTAL:"t2}}'
```

But you can do the full thing in GNU awk, in the following way:

```
$ awk 'ENDFILE{print FILENAME":"FNR}END{print "TOTAL:"NR}' *.c *.h
```

Comment: The first one with `END{print $1}` will only do what you want in some awks since the values of $0, $1, etc. are undefined in the END section per POSIX. In some awks (e.g. gawk) they'll have the value of the last record read, in others they'll be null, and in others still they could be anything at all and still be POSIX compliant.

Comment: @EdMorton Valid point. Thanks for pointing this out. I had no clue.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
$ wc -l *.c *.h | awk '{ if(NR>1) print x; x=$2":"$1 } END { print toupper(x) } '
file1.c:4
file2.c:4
file3.h:3
TOTAL:11

$
```

or using Perl

```
$  wc -l *.c *.h | awk '{print $2":"$1}' | perl -pe ' { $_=uc $_ if eof } '
file1.c:4
file2.c:4
file3.h:3
TOTAL:11

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tr [a-z] [A-Z] < "input file(s)".*
```

Prints out the content of the file to upper. Otherwise, try below:

```
wc -l *.c *.h | awk '{print toupper($2)":"toupper($1)}'
```

Not sure whether this is going to work.

Comment: this makes all file names Uppcercases , I need just the total to be printed uppercase.Thx anyway

Comment: So you just need to print out the content to uppercase?

Comment: I need the word "total" that is returned by wc to be printed uppercase.

Comment: ‘*And use -c instead of -l*’ What?! Why? The two mean different things, and OP is using `-l`. Why would you tell them to use `-c`?!

Comment: You are right, @Biffen. Changed back to -l :) ´. Misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/total/{$1=toupper($1)}1' file

file1.c:1000
file2.c:0
file3.h:5
TOTAL:1005
```

Comment: This will be incorrect if you have a file named "total" or has the word total in it.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.